# Getting absolute nanotime without JNI

Tags: java, jvm

With `System.currentTimeMillis()` we have absolute time that we can use across vms, but with `System.nanoTime()` as its documentation says `The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time...`.

If we can acurately get our jvm start time and this `some fixed` point to which nano time is relative to we can get absolute nano time with about the same speed as millis since other variables do not change its simply few math operations away from being absolute nano time.

`absoluteNanoTime = vmStartTimeMS * 1000 + (System.nanoTime() - nanoStartPoint)`

The start time of the vm can be found with `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime()`

**How can i get the *nanoStartPoint* from JVM?**

So in a nutshell the goal is to have absolute nanotime that works as fast as System.nanoTime (ignore few cycles to do the math) and not use JNI to call some OS dependent clocks.

Comment: http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.fi/2012/02/what-is-behind-systemnanotime.html no chance buddy.

Comment: Since Java 9 `Instant.now()` has nanosecond resolution, see [JDK-8068730](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730)

Comment: BTW, your formula will not work, because `System.nanoTime()` is not related to wall-clock time. E.g. `nanoTime` it is not guaranteed to include the period when the system is suspended.

Comment: You don’t need to base that calculation on the JVM starting time. You can do `final long absMS = System.currentTimeMillis(), nanoBase = System.nanoTime();` at an arbitrary point of time and use that for `absoluteNanoTime = absMS * 1000000 + (System.nanoTime() - nanoBase)` (I took the freedom to fix your factor). But that doesn’t solve the fundamental problems of that idea. First, combining a value of millisecond precision with another will never give you something better than millisecond precision . Second, as @apangin already said, these are two timelines which are not congruent.

Comment: On Windows and Linux, System.nanoTime() is the time since the machine started and can be used across JVMs on the same machine.

Comment: BTW There is 1,000,000 ns in a ms, not 1,000.

Comment: System.nanoTime() is monotonically increasing which means it doesn't correct for any clock drift and over time will drift from the wall clock unless it is continuously resynchronized. It can be 1 ms per hour out.

Comment: For what purpose do you need sub-millisecond precision? Some solutions may have some edge-cases but still be sufficient for some use-cases.

Comment: @the8472 its a distributed computation problem, where things in different jvm's can happen faster than a millisecond, hence i need nano or at least micro precision... just don't want to do nasty JNI and OS dependant binaries...

Comment: Thanks everyone, i was just pseudo-coding the idea so no attention to factors. Unfortunately i didn't know that nanotime will drift away from wall clock time over time, that alone makes this useless, I guess i'll have to make the leap and upgrade to java 9+, if someone wants to summarise all of this as answer please do.